# jquery как присвоить переменной содержимое соседнего элемента

Tags: jquery

Есть много одинаковых кусков `html`, нужно в переменную `get_spanText` "положить" текст из `class_2_1 varSpan`, подскажите пожалуйста как это правильно сделать через `this`. Делал как внизу - в переменной ничего нет - пустая строка

```js
$('.class_1').click(function(){
  
  var get_spanText = $(this).next(".class_2").cildren(".class_2_1").find("span").text();
  console.log(get_spanText);
  $('.someClass').html(get_spanText+' ');
  
    
 });
```

```html
<div class="class_1" id="id1">
  <img src="#">
</div>
<div class="class_2">
  <ul>
 <li class="class_2_1">Title <span>varSpan</span></li>
 <li class="class_2_2">someText</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.class_1').click(function() {
  var get_spanText = $(this).next(".class_2").find(".class_2_1 span").text();
  console.log(get_spanText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class_1" id="id1">
  <img src="#">
</div>
<div class="class_2">
  <ul>
    <li class="class_2_1">Title <span>varSpan</span></li>
    <li class="class_2_2">someText</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```